# Regex for a splitting a mathematical expression

Tags: javascript

I have an expression of for "1+2-4*5+0.9+10.5+..." in string format and I want to split it into an array so that every number from the second one onwards in the expression is paired with the math operation before it. (i.e. ["+2","-4","*5,...]). I have attempted using regex `/[-+*/][0-9]+|[-+*/][.0-9]+|[-+*/][0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g` and am succeeding in spitting whole numbers but anything after a decimal point is not captured (see attached code snippet). How do I modify the last part of the regex (i.e. [-+*/][0-9]+.[0-9]+) so that it works properly for all decimal fraction?

```js
expression="5-0.23+.65+.9+0.5+10.5";
const numArr=expression.match(/[-+*/][0-9]+|[-+*/][.0-9]+|[-+*/][0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g);
console.log(numArr);
console.log("As you can see the regex is failing to capture decimals unless they start with a period(.)")
```

Comment: If you're writing a mathematical expression parser, you might consider turning your input to [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) - ie, this is a solved problem and regex is not necessarily the right way to go!

Comment: @Jamiec Reverse Polish Notation is a new topic to me, as a novice developer. I'm using the regex to implement an "immediate execution logic" for my calculator App (coding bootcamp stuff...). I had originally used JS eval function but it didn't work so well for some expressions so I needed to come up with another way.

Comment: The shunting alorithm is actually quite easy to implement and makes executing your calculation a load easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex inside a split() method:

```js
expression="5-0.23+.65+.9+0.5+10.5";
const numArr = expression.split(/(?=\-)|(?=\+)/g)
console.log(numArr)
```

Comment: Nice. FYI for the OP: this is using "lookahead assertions": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions

Comment: Thanks a lot for thank, works perfectly. @Chris, that's a good read, thanks.